# postgresql: creating database in a specified location

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a PG db in a specified location. According to the docs [here](http://www.commandprompt.com/ppbook/x17149), I must use the LOCATION flag. However, when I run `CREATE DATABASE (from the pgsql CLI)`, I get the following warning:

```
WARNING:  LOCATION is not supported anymore
HINT:  Consider using tablespaces instead.
```

However, the PG documentation on TABLESPACES does not show how it can be used to create a database in a specific directory. What is the required syntax to do this?

Comment: The book is from 2002, avoid using it as a reference.

Comment: You could lookup the `CREATE TABLESPACE` command in the fine manual here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtablespace.html , and than do a create datbase : http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createdatabase.html referring to that location

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You would need to do this in 2 steps:

1. [Create Tablespace](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtablespace.html) examples for which you can see in the link
2. [Create Database](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdatabase.html)

When you create tablespace you set it's location and then you can create multiple databases in the same tablespace if you choose to.

Answer (score 3):

CREATE TABLESPACE fastspace LOCATION '/mnt/sda1/postgresql/data';

See the chapter about [tablespaces](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/manage-ag-tablespaces.html) in the manual.

Comment: Like I said, that reference does not show how to use tablespaces in a **CREATE DATABASE** command

Comment: Actually it [does](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdatabase.html).

Comment: CREATE DATABASE name TABLESPACE = tablespace or you can set a default tablespace so that everything created will be in that table space like so: SET default_tablespace = tablespace;